# How do I send a mail with conditional "CC"

Tags: node.js, express, email, axios, sendgrid

I am trying to send a password reset mail, and I need to send a specific type with "cc" if it is a subaccount that wants to reset, so that the superaccount get copied in the mail. I am using a mail worker and it is in a microservice architecture. Below is where I am handling the mail.

```
passwordReset: ({ action, parameters: { recipients }, tenant_id, template_id, ...payload }) => {
        appSource = getAppSource(tenant_id)

        let mail_data = {
            "from": {
                "email": appSource.sender,
                "name": appSource.senderName
            },
            "personalizations": [{
                "to": [{
                    "email": recipients[0].email
                }],
                "cc": [{
                    "email": payload.cc_email !== null ? payload.cc_email : ""
                }],
                "dynamic_template_data": {
                    "email": recipients[0].email,
                    "link": recipients[0]['link']
                }
            }],
            "template_id": appSource.templates.passwordReset
        }

        sendgrid.post('', mail_data)
            .then(({ data }) => console.log("Mail sent for action: PasswordReset"))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    },
```

When there is a "cc" this works, and mail is sent, but when there is no "cc", I get a bad 400 request from sendgrid, because the "cc" value is an empty string and sendgrid wants an actual email.

I have been able to get around this temporarily by attaching a junk mail, but this raises concerns on the part of the users when they see a "cc" in their password reset mail

```
"cc": [{
    "email": payload.cc_email !== null ? payload.cc_email : appSource.senderOps
}]
```

How can I write this aspect to avoid the "cc" key in the object as this flaw is coming from Sendgrid not been able to handle an empty field in the personalizations array?

Answer (score 0):

With this approach simply send an empty array if `payload.cc_email` does not exist. If it does exist, then send the array with the cc email included. If you don't send an invalid email, you won't get an error, so just don't send one at all and avoid confusion from your clients and workarounds in your code.

```
passwordReset: ({ action, parameters: { recipients }, tenant_id, template_id, ...payload }) => {
    appSource = getAppSource(tenant_id)

    let mail_data = {
            "from": {
                    "email": appSource.sender,
                    "name": appSource.senderName
            },
            "personalizations": [{
                    "to": [{
                            "email": recipients[0].email
                    }],
                    "cc": payload.cc_email !== null ? [{"email": payload.cc_email}] : [],
                    "dynamic_template_data": {
                            "email": recipients[0].email,
                            "link": recipients[0]['link']
                    }
            }],
            "template_id": appSource.templates.passwordReset
    }

    sendgrid.post('', mail_data)
            .then(({ data }) => console.log("Mail sent for action: PasswordReset"))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err))
},
```

Comment: Thanks @daddygames, it was helpful. I came up with another method tho'

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I followed this logic like so, to solve the "cc" issue.

```
passwordReset: ({ action, parameters: { recipients }, tenant_id, template_id, ...payload }) => {
        appSource = getAppSource(tenant_id)

        let personalizationData = {
            "to": [{
                "email": recipients[0].email
            }],
            "dynamic_template_data": {
                "email": recipients[0].email,
                "link": recipients[0]['link']
            }
        }

        if (payload.cc_email) {
            personalizationData.cc = [{
                "email": payload.cc_email
            }]
        }

        let mail_data = {
            "from": {
                "email": appSource.sender,
                "name": appSource.senderName
            },
            "personalizations": [personalizationData],
            "template_id": appSource.templates.passwordReset
        }
        sendgrid.post('', mail_data)
            .then(({ data }) => console.log("Mail sent for action: PasswordReset"))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err.response.data.errors))
    },
```

So, "cc" does not get into the personalizations object if it's not in the payload data.